# $n$-dimensional cylindrical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

### Prerequisites

I am working on a numerical integration routine [VAMP](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806432) [Ohl 1998] specializing on finding narrow peaks in smooth integrand. This works by using multiple instances of the adaptive Monte Carlo [VEGAS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999178900049?via%3Dihub) [Lepage 1978] algorithm in different coordinate systems, each fit adapt to one peak of the function. In the end the different results are combined to compute the final integral.

To test it, I am constructing normalized function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with peaks in cartesian, polar, cylindrical and spherical coordinates. It consists of [Lorentzian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html) peaks (not normalized, as they cannot be normalized in higher dimensions)
$$ L_{x_0}^b = \frac{b}{(x-x_0)^2 + b^2},
\qquad \int\mathrm dx\, L_{x_0}^b(x) = \arctan\left(\frac{x-x_x}{b}\right) $$
for radial components of the different coordinate systems added up and normalized so $\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm dx^3\,f(x) \equiv1$. (The radial Jacobian determinants of the coordinate systems are cancelled out, so only the Lorentzians remain, as the angular parts can be integrated to the full solid angle.)
$$
f(x) = \frac{b}{24\pi\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2b}\right)}\left(
\frac{\Theta(r_3<1)}{r_3^2\left(\left(r_3-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+b^2\right)}
+ \frac{\Theta(r_2<1,|x_3|<1)}{r_2^2\left(\left(r_2-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+b^2\right)}
+ \frac{2\pi\Theta(-1<x_1,x_2,x_3<1)}{x_1^2+(2b)^2}
\right)
$$
where $r_2:=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $r_3:=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$, and $\Theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside function which is $1$ if the argument is true and $0$ otherwise. This makes it easy to vary the parameter $b$, the width of the Lorentzian, and therefore the difficulty of numerical integration. For two dimensions (just dropping the $r_3$-term), the function looks like this:

[image: 2d Lorentzian test function]

As you can see, it has peaks around the radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and the $x_1$-axis. Therefore it will be hard to sample efficiently with pure VEGAS, but in VAMP we use polar *and* cartesian coordinates, making it possible to sample both peaks efficiently.

---

### Question

I now want to benchmark the algorithm in higher dimensions (as this is important for the physical application), and therefore construct a similar function for $n$ dimensions, consisting of $n$ terms with Lorentzians in $r_n,\,r_{n-1},\,\ldots,\,r_2,\,x_1$. But I also need **$n$-dimensional cylindrical coordinates**.

In 3D, [cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) are constructed by using polar coordinates on one plane and just adding the $x_3$ coordinate orthogonally to that, thereby reducing the radial dimension by 1 (compared to full [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)), as can be seen in their respective Jacobains $r$ vs $r^2\sin\theta$.

I would like to stack up Lorentzians in the radial components of one hyperplanes for each dimenion (I hope this is the correct way of expressing it): One along one axis, one in $r_2$, one in $r_3$ and so on until $r_n$. Then I want to equip my algorithm with coordinate systems suitable to sample each peak efficiently, aka having a coordinate system where that $r_i$ is one of the coordinate axis. As I am in $n>2$ dimensions, I cannot use polar coordinates for the $r_2$, but I can use cylindrical coordinates, which "embed" polar coordinates.

For spherical coordinates there is a well [defined generalization to $n$ dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), consisting of $1$ radius and $n-1$ angles. The formula for mappings and Jacobians is relatively straight forward and easy to implement for variable dimension.

**My Question**: Is there a something like generalized cylindrical coordinates for $n$ dimensions?

Is it possible to just use spherical coordinates in $m$ dimensions and just attach $n-m$ orthogonal cartesian coordinates to it? Like in 4D:

- Full Sphercial $r,\,\phi_1,\,\phi_2,\,\phi_3$
  $$\begin{eqnarray}
  x_1 & = & r\cos\phi_1\\
  x_2 & = & r\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2\\
  x_3 & = & r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\cos\phi_3\\
  x_4 & = & r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\sin\phi_3\\
  \end{eqnarray}$$
- 4,3 cylindrical $r\equiv r_3,\,\phi_1,\,\phi_2,\,x_4$ (embedded 3D spherical)
  $$\begin{eqnarray}
  x_1 & = & r\cos\phi_1\\
  x_2 & = & r\sin\phi_1\cos\phi_2\\
  x_3 & = & r\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_2\\
  x_4
  \end{eqnarray}$$
- 4,2 cylindrical $r\equiv r_2,\,\phi,x_3,\,x_4$ (embedded 2D cylindrical aka polar)
  $$\begin{eqnarray}
  x_1 & = & r\cos\phi\\
  x_2 & = & r\sin\phi\\
  x_3 \\
  x_4
  \end{eqnarray}$$

Would this be a valid coordinate system? Is this as easily generalizable as it seems? Are there pitfalls that I didn't think of? What about the domains? Is there literature on this and where can I find it?

Comment: How do you mean "Would this be a valid coordinate system?"? What could be invalid about it? It looks fine. Another approach would be to use polar coordinates in $\frac n2$ planes:

$$
x_1=r_{12}\cos\phi_{12}\\
x_2=r_{12}\sin\phi_{12}\\
x_3=r_{34}\cos\phi_{34}\\
x_4=r_{34}\sin\phi_{34}\\
\ldots
$$

Comment: @joriki It could be not normalized, not orthogonal (that's still valid and I didn't ask for that, still could be a problem). But it could also have problems with non-unique points or could be non-invertible or something else. I believe the example I provided is perfectly fine, I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: What does it mean for a coordinate system to be normalized? As to non-unique points and invertibility, these coordinate systems will of course all suffer from the same singularities as polar coordinates and spherical coordinates do, with all angles specifying the same point at $r=0$, all angles $\phi$ specifying the same point at $\theta=0$ and the like.

Comment: I meant they should have unit basis vectors. Which they obviously do. Just wanted to make sure I don't miss anything. Same with polar singularities. I just wanted to check if there is any other caveats that arise from this combination of systems that are not present in the individual parts themselves.